# How do you add Facebook like/share buttons for sections of a webpage not the whole page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I'm designing a static website in HTML/CSS and one of the pages will have a list of items. How do you add a like/share button for the individual items not the whole page? For example:

```
<body>
    <div class="item1">Content</div>
    <div class="item2">Content</div>
    <div class="item3">Content</div>
</body>
```

Add a like/share button for just the content in the div "item1" not the whole page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change out the links to the page items you want people to like.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

 <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/"        data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by changing out the links? Which links are you referring to? The info in a div may just be a pic with a bit of text that I want people to be able to like/or share.

Answer (score 0):

data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" above should be pointed toward your facebook page. For example,

For Example the following goes just below the  tag in your code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

    <header>
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://https://www.facebook.com/simpaticUSA" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true">
        </div>
```